# Can beej mantra be initiated someone other than guru?

Tags: vedas, shiva, mantras, tantra, kali

Let's say I want to do kreem mantra sandhna so can someone who's not by guru(but have sidh the kreem mantra) initiate me

Comment: Once he initiates you he becomes your Guru .. And if he is Siddha in that mantra then he is capable of initiating you too.

Comment: The guru is the conduit for the bija mantra. The mantra is given by God. If not done through through your guru, the power of the bija mantra is not conveyed. You also may not get the proper pronunciation. The correct sound is the proper vibration. Can you sing a song in the wrong key or by hitting the wrong note?